# RDS Session Host RDP SSL Certificate Expiring

Tags: certificate, rds

We have RDS Deployed with:

- RD Connection Broker
- RD Session Host
- RD Licensing
- RD Gateway
- RD Web Access

..

For your information our Gateway server name is rdp.sparkorg.org

**To renew the RDS Certificate, I have..**

1) Generated a CSR in IIS

2) Completed the signing request

3) Exported as PFX (With Private Key)

4) Binded the certificate with the RDWeb IIS Instance

5) With the PFX, gone into 'Deployment Properties' and applied a COMODO (Previously exported) aginast, RD Connection Broker, RD Web Access & RD Gateway.
[image: Overview of certificates applied]

6) All looks to be good.. I presume I have installed correctly..

**The problem I am having is:**

When I attempt to connect to a RemoteApp, I see the following window..

[image]

I would imagine that the above is expected due to said session host having a .local internal DNS Name.. **My question is, how do I renew this self signed certificate?**

The self signed Certificate is expiring soon.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A selfsigned certificate is not trusted. If you need to use selfsigned certificates you need to distribute the certificate to all clients to ensure they trust it.